# Android Google Play Services Without Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services, google-oauth

I'm considering making a custom Android tablet running a 99.99% AOSP ROM. My life would be much easier if Google Play Services was available to me while writing apps for it, but I can't find any official information anywhere regarding installing Google Play Services as a standalone app (no GApps or Play Store). I'd like to be able to use Google+ sign in with my app, but if that's not possible I'll have to revert to asking the user for their username + password / oath2.

Does anyone have any information on what I should do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome [to attempt to license Google Play Services and the rest of the Google commercial components](http://source.android.com/source/faqs.html#if-my-device-is-compatible-does-it-automatically-have-access-to-google-play-and-branding) for your Android tablet.